# What is the difference between keras.backend.max vs keras.backend.argmax?

Tags: python, keras

I am a beginner in Deep Learning and while performing a practical assignment, came across the Keras documentation on [keras.backend](https://keras.io/backend/).

I went through the explanation a number of times. however, i cannot exactly understand the difference between max and argmax function.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I will explain this using `max` and `argmax` from the `numpy` package, but the two functions are identical to the ones in the Keras backend:

```
import numpy as np
vector = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])
```

Now, `np.max(vector)` returns the number `3`, as this is the maximal *value* in the vector. `np.argmax(vector)` however returns `2`, as this is the *index* of the maximal value in the vector.

The `argmax` function is often used to post-process the output of a softmax layer. Say the output layer of your classifier (which classifies some image into one of four classes) is

```
output = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(...)
```

and the output of `predict(some_random_image)` is `[0.02, 0.90, 0.06, 0.02]`. Then, `argmax([0.02, 0.90, 0.06, 0.02])` immediately gives you the class (`1`).

Comment: ohh.. so max will return the actual value and argmax will just return the index for that value.
Thanks a lot for your answer @IonicSolutions

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also added an example how the `argmax` function is regularly used in classification problems. (If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thanks!)

Comment: Why isn't argmax named  'max_index'? The distinction between the two is simple enough to express using proper naming conventions.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on arg max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) nicely explains why the function is called `argmax`.